# fullpage.js results in nprogress and other javascript problems

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

I'm having this issue on https://www.rewardslive.com/test
Once the page is loaded, everything is fine, but when you click to another page which is handled by ajax, the loading bar slowly moves and never seems to end. I'm also using nprogress and other javascript, and this messes up the other javascript Do I need to make it so that fullpage.js is included on every page? How would I disable fullpage after leaving the page? Is there some variable?

When i move to another page, js console throws this error: 
Error: cannot call methods on tooltip prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'hide'
Essentially, i think it is conflicting with the proper scripts I have on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean when you say that

> the loading bar slowly moves and never seems to end

But there's no way to "destroy" the plugin but you could disable some of the functions you might have problems with.

You should turn autoScrolling off by using the public method inside some event, for example:

```
$('#element').click(function(){
    $.fn.fullpage.setAutoScrolling(false);

    //dynamically load of your selected link
    $.load(.....)
});
```